# Clojure map-like flow-through function

Tags: clojure, lisp

I'm writing a simple photo library app in Clojure. I have a `library` map that has the `:photos` key which is a vector of photo maps. Then, I have a function that adds a photo to a library---it takes the library object and the photo to be added as arguments.

```
(defn add-to-library [library photo]
  ...
)
```

It returns a `library` map with the `photo` added.

Now, I want to "map" this function over a list of photos. I need to be able to pass the `library` object through from one iteration to the next.

What is the idiomatic way of doing this in Clojure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

`(reduce add-to-library library list-of-photos)`.

The [`reduce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce) function is wonderful, and is a general tool that is surprisingly applicable in a lot of specific situations. Many of those situations are ones like yours, where you have a "collection of things", a "function that adds a thing to that collection", and a "list of things to add". Maybe this isn't starting material if first learning about `reduce`, but I found it very interesting: http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html